# Java uninstalled but still java -version is showing 1.7?

Tags: macos, mac, java

I am just testing my desktop application for mac, it requires java 7. I have uninstalled java and I want to reinstalled it. But when I type `java -version` in terminal it still shows 1.7.
I am a new bee to mac. It might be a very basic question but it would be great if anyone over here can help me out.

Comment: I'm not sure why that would be. I assume you're running OSX 10.7+? (Since you have Java 7, of course).

Comment: Yes I am... I am too confused why it is working. I installed the Java 7 using http://www.java.com/en/download/help/mac_uninstall_java.xml I guess that link is missing something.

Answer (score 2):

There was [an article from Oracle](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/mac_uninstall_java.xml) that talked about uninstalling Java 7 but was actually referring to just the Java Applet Plugin (`/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin`).  The Java software that you see from the command line is at `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`.  To determine which directory you are actually using for the java program, enter `which java` from the terminal window.  There is a symbolic link in the `/usr/bin` directory but I wouldn't count on it pointing to the correct location.

Comment: The Java-related symlinks in `/usr/bin` do not point to installed Oracle JVMs; they point to Apple's "JavaVM" support framework, which is a layer of indirection on top of them, which uses `/usr/libexec/java_home` or similar mechanisms to select on of the installed third-party JVMs to pass calls on to.

Comment: And here's a different article which describes the particular steps to uninstall the whole JVM, not just the Applet Plug-in. http://sandro.knot.org/blog/2012/08/uninstalling-java-for-os-x/. And Oracle has more-correct but not complete instructions in the installation doc at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/mac/mac-jdk.html#uninstall.